# Adding a condition to deletion of several BST nodes

Tags: java

I finally got my BST working and its functions, although now I want to delete all nodes that have a key that is equal or less than 75.

I tried to add the operation as: `theTree.remove(key<=75);` and multiple other ways, I know the syntax to do such a thing is wrong but I can't seem to find relevant information online as to how to do it. Any advice will help.

Code:

```
public class DatosTarea9 {

   Node root;
   public void addNode(int key, String name) {
       Node newNode = new Node(key, name);

       if(root == null) {
           root = newNode;
       }
       else {
           Node focusNode = root;
           Node parent;
           while(true) {
               parent = focusNode;
               if(key < focusNode.key) {
                      focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                      if(focusNode == null) {
                          parent.leftChild = newNode;
                          return;
           }
         }
               else {
                   focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                   if(focusNode == null) {
                       parent.rightChild = newNode;
                       return;
                   }
               }
       }
     }
   }

   public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {
       if(focusNode != null){
           inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
           System.out.println(focusNode);
           inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
       }
   }

   public boolean remove(int key) {
       Node focusNode = root;
       Node parent = root;

       boolean isItALeftChild = true;

       while (focusNode.key != key){
           parent = focusNode;
           if(key < focusNode.key){
               isItALeftChild = true;

               focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
           }
           else {
               isItALeftChild = false;
               focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
           }
           if(focusNode == null)
                   return false;
       }
       if (focusNode.leftChild == null && focusNode.rightChild == null){
           if(focusNode == root){
               root = null;
           }
           else if(isItALeftChild){
               parent.leftChild = null;   
           }
           else {
               parent.rightChild = null;
           }
       }
       else if(focusNode.rightChild == null){
           if(focusNode == root)
               root = focusNode.leftChild;
           else if(isItALeftChild)
               parent.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;
           else parent.rightChild = focusNode.leftChild;
       }
       else if(focusNode.leftChild == null){
           if(focusNode == root)
               root = focusNode.rightChild;
           else if(isItALeftChild)
               parent.leftChild = focusNode.rightChild;
           else
               parent.rightChild = focusNode.leftChild;
       }
       else {
           Node replacement = getReplacementNode(focusNode);

           if(focusNode == root)
               root = replacement;

               else if (isItALeftChild)
                   parent.leftChild = replacement;
               else
                   parent.rightChild = replacement;
               replacement.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;
           }
           return true;
       }


   public Node getReplacementNode(Node replacedNode){
       Node replacementParent = replacedNode;
       Node replacement = replacedNode;

       Node focusNode = replacedNode.rightChild;

       while (focusNode != null){
           replacementParent = replacement;
           replacement = focusNode;
           focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
       }
       if(replacement != replacedNode.rightChild){
           replacementParent.leftChild = replacement.rightChild;
           replacement.rightChild = replacedNode.rightChild;
       }
       return replacement;
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       DatosTarea9 theTree = new DatosTarea9();
       theTree.addNode(82, "Jorge");
       theTree.addNode(74, "Javier");
       theTree.addNode(66, "Jose");
       theTree.addNode(38, "Jaime");
       theTree.addNode(94, "Andres");
       theTree.addNode(88, "Alejandro");
       theTree.addNode(42, "Adrian");
       theTree.addNode(79, "Alan");

       System.out.println("Remove all keys below 75");
       theTree.remove(key<=75);

       theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
    }
}

class Node {
    int key;
    String name;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, String name) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name + " has a key " + key;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a helper `removeWithCondition()` and pass in a comparator or predicate function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I couldn't find any documentacion regarding `removeWithCondition()` and how to implement it though

Comment: Why would you find documentation for that? Plus, the only way to remove all nodes that satisfy a condition would be to do an inOrderTraversal and remove at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't find any documentation on it until after you wrote and published them. The idea is you'll have to implement that yourself.

For an example how you could pass the functionality you're looking for into a method as I suggested would be like:

```
public void removeByPredicate(Predicate<Node> predicate) {
    removeByPredicate(root, predicate);
}
```

That calls the private method of the same name to remove *a* node that passes the predicate test. You could use it like:

```
    Tree t = new Tree();
    t.removeByPredicate(n -> n.key <= 75);
```

And you use the predicate function like:

```
if (predicate.test(node))
    remove(node);
```

That might get you going. The nice thing is the test can change dynamically to whatever suits your needs at that time. As pointed out in a comment, it would require a little more thinking to get *all* of the nodes removed.